# Issue with Layout Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-mapview

I want to create a simple interface with a `MapView` on top and a `Button` on bottom to refresh said `MapView`. Both the elements should `fill_parent` in *width*, but I want them to not overlap in *height*. My problem is that my mapview seems to overlap with my `Button` and hide it. This is my `layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <com.google.android.maps.MapView
          android:id="@+id/mapview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:apiKey="my_api_key" /> 

     <Button 
          android:id="@+id/close"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:text="@string/title_close" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a RelativeLayout
2. Place a button as a first child with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, make it `layout_width="fill_parent"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`
3. Place MapView second with `layout_above="@id/close"`
4. Make it `layout_width="fill_parent"` and `layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: And don't forget using `layout_height="wrap_content"` on the button

Comment: great, ty for the help. Do you by any chance have any reference to a tutorial? apart from the one in the developer.android.com

Answer (score 0):

You must to use layout_weight to adjust the size of the button and map
Button better with layout_height="wrap_content"

try map with weight = 0.5 and button with 2 or something like this